# Split each row in a file into substrings with delimiter based on fixed length

Tags: linux, string, split, offset, delimiter

I need some help here to convert a file into a new file with below requirement:

> 1. Split each row (long string) into sub-string based on fixed length
> 2. use pipe delimiter "|" between each sub-string
> 3. leave last undefined column (sub-string) as-is, but add "|" before it.

Here is example, suppose a file (test.dat) has 2 rows:

```
PG123ABCD A 000{000
MK789HJKL32H00

Column 1: length(2)
Column 2: length(3) 
Column 3: length(4)
Column 4: length(3)
Column 5: undefined, use all remaining value
```

Below is the final output I need.  The example has only 2 rows,  suppose I have a file that have 1k+ similar rows, and I need to convert original file to a new file based on above requirement.

```
PG|123|ABCD| A |000{000
MK|789|HJKL|32H|00
```

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: You might want to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use Stack Overflow effectively. In the meantime, maybe [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com) or [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com) can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cut -b 1-2,3-5,6-9,10-12,13-500 --output-delimiter='|' test.dat > 1.dat
```

I wrote above code and it output exactly what I need.

> The only question I have is last column, I used **13-500** as fixed length for the undefined column,  however the length of the undefined remaining string varies in different rows, is there a generic way to define the last column's length? e.g., something like **13-max_lengh_of_the_row**

Comment: you can use `13-` to specify from the 13th character onward

Comment: thank you @Bertrand Martel, that works!